# Mi lista desplegable se cierra una vez hago click en ella

Tags: html, angular

Recientemente cree una función que se encarga de eliminar un elemento de mi lista desplegable (de notificaciones), pero cuando hago click dentro de la ventana esta se cierra, agradecería algún tipo de ayuda o información para evitarlo. A continuación el código de JS:

```
clearNotification(idx) {
    this._notificationsService.markNotificationsAsReaded(this.notification) 
       .then(res=>{
            this._notificationsService.deleteNotific(res)   
       })
}
```

y este es el codigo HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    <i role="button" class="fas fa-check-double (click)="clearNotification( notification ) "></i>
</div>
```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda.

Comment: Está mal cerrada tu class del html. Seguro es eso